# List<String[]> - Need suggestion as how to pull record from String[]

Tags: c#, linq

I have a text file that contains 1000's of rows (around 30 column each row) and need to pull desired row based on some condition.

using below code I have the collection ready from text file into List

```
string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(path);
List<string> listOfStr = new List<string>(records);
```

I need to query a particular column of each row... if that match with criteria.. I need that record...
How can I do this using linq? Or any other approach ?

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: [This link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) is where I started when I had a similar question.. Just sayin'

Comment: When you say "column of each row", do you mean you're trying to determine the character at a particular offset within the string?

Comment: We will need more info on the data, but if you want to query 'fields' then i would split up each column into a property in a custom class, create a list<customclass> and use linq

Comment: Thanks to all for response... I tried all options but none is working, not sure why? my data looks like below ( Few more info.  tab is used as delimiter, there are no column name in the text file... I am simply using index to query.... ),                                                             2013-06-20 11:09:20 123456789 20130620 20130615

Comment: looks like I need to first insert these records from text file to some class and then query using linq  or is there any other way I can directly query the text file records and pull matching row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the lines into columns:

```
List<string[]> listOfStr = records.Select(s => s.Split('\t')).ToList();
```

You can use the `Where` method to filter on a condition.

This for example filters out all rows where the fifth column is `"Hello"`:

```
List<string[]> result = listOfStr
  .Where(s => s[4] == "Hello")
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks GUFFA for response... I tried all options but none is working, not sure why? my data looks like below ( Few more info. tab is used as delimiter, there are no column name in the text file... I am simply using index to query.... ), 2013-06-20 11:09:20 123456789 20130620 20130615

Comment: @Amit: First split the lines into columns. I added code for that above.

Comment: Thanks GUFFA, split was required first to get the desired result. :) Thanks a lot to all for your help.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `File.ReadLines` instead which streams the lines instead of loading all into memory first. Also, you are creating two in-memory collections here:

```
string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(path);
List<string> listOfStr = new List<string>(records);
```

This is much more efficient in terms of memory consumption:

```
var matchingLines = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(l => new{ Parts = l.Split(), Line = l })
    .Where(x => x.Parts.ElementAtOrDefault(9) == yourSearch)
    .Select(x => x.Line);

foreach (string line in matchingLines)
     Console.WriteLine(line);
```

You haven't mentioned what delimiter separates each column, i have used white-spaces, `l.Split(',')` would split by comma. `Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault(9)` retuns the 10th column if available, otherwise `null` is returned.

Comment: Thanks TIM for response... I tried all options but none is working, not sure why? my data looks like below ( Few more info. tab is used as delimiter, there are no column name in the text file... I am simply using index to query.... ), 2013-06-20 11:09:20 123456789 20130620 20130615

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the lines are separated by comma:

```
int indexCol = 0; //the index of the col you want to look into
string search = string.Empty; //what you want to search in the column

string lineResult = listOfStr.FirstOfDefault(x=> x.split(",")[indexCol].Contains(search));
```

Other

```
string search = string.Empty;

foreach (string line in listOfSrt)
{
    string[] inCols = line.Split("\t");

    if (inCols[0].Contains(search))
    {
     Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks MTzaldo for response... I tried all options but none is working, not sure why? my data looks like below ( Few more info. tab is used as delimiter, there are no column name in the text file... I am simply using index to query.... ), 2013-06-20 11:09:20 123456789 20130620 20130615

Comment: did you tried using "\t" in the split function?
`string lineResult = listOfStr.FirstOfDefault(x=> x.split("\t")[indexCol].Contains(search));`

Comment: I tried like this as I was getting error..string lineResult = listOfStr.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Split(ch,StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Contains(valuetoSearch));    where ch = string[] ch = {"/t"};

Comment: /t is different from \t . You must use \t to specify that is a tab.

Comment: sorry that was typo from me... I am using \t only

Comment: I edited my answer check if that helps. With the foreach you will be able to look what is happening. You can put a debug stop inside the loop to know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(path);
List<string> listOfStr = new List<string>(records);
List<string> listOfMatches = listOfStr.Where(str => str[YOUR TEST COLUMN].Equals([YOUR TEST VALUE])).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks STLDeveloper for response... I tried all options but none is working, not sure why? my data looks like below ( Few more info. tab is used as delimiter, there are no column name in the text file... I am simply using index to query.... ), 2013-06-20 11:09:20 123456789 20130620 20130615